# Diffeomorphism between $n$-fold and $m$-fold tori

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Consider $M_n, M_m$ which are an n-fold torus and an m-fold torus, respectively, in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Prove that there exists a map $f:M_n\to M_m$ which is a local diffeomorphism if and only if $$m-1|n-1$$ for $m\ge1$.

Comment: You probably mean «Show that there exists a map $f:M_n\to M_n$ which is a local diffeomorphism if and only if $m-1\mid n-1$».

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yes , i edited my question

Comment: In your title you also do not mean "diffeomorphism": as you know, there is no diffeomorphism unless $n$ and $m$ are equal. Being clear, precise and concise is the objective.

Comment: I have to say that I don't understand why this was closed...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f:M_n\to M_m$ is a local diffeomorphism. Since the surfaces are compact, the map is proper and [then it is a covering map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860351/a-proper-local-diffeomorphism-between-manifolds-is-a-covering-map). It follows that [the Euler characteristic of $M_m$ divides that of $M_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369456/euler-characteristic-of-a-covering-space), that is $$2-2m=\chi(M_m)\mid\chi(M_n)=2-2n.$$ It follows that your condition is necessary.

For sufficiency, you have to construct a map. One way to do that is to construct first a surface $M_\infty$ which is an infinite chain, like 
[image]
but with infinitely many links. On such a surface the group $\mathbb Z$ acts, and if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $a$ divides $b$, then you can consider the quotients $M_\infty/a\mathbb Z$ and $M_\infty/b\mathbb Z$, which are surfaces and the obvious induced map $$M_\infty/a\mathbb Z\to M_\infty/b\mathbb Z.$$ This map is a covering and in this way you can realize coverings in all cases that they exist (although not all possible coverings are of this form!)

Comment: Sorry ! How can I construct this map in order to reach sufficiency

Comment: @Albert, do you have any idea as how to do that, at least in an example?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The easiest construction of this is probably to write your surface as a "keychain", with a center ring and genus n-1 handles attached around the center surface. Then the covering map is quotienting by the action of $\Bbb Z/d$ given by rotation.